# Tubeless tire deflating through sidewall

Tags: mountain-bike, tubeless

On my mountain bike I have Continental X-King tires (tubeless ready) on tubeless ready rims. I rode them a couple of times with tubes and now I went for tubeless setup with Stan's NoTubes Sealant.

At first everything looked fine, but they keep on deflating slowly. From 3 bar to 1 bar in roughly 10 hours. I've submerged the tires in water to see what's wrong. There are no major cuts or holes, just very small bubbles are leaking through the sidewalls. I did a couple of rides to distribute the sealant inside the tire, I also tried leaving the wheel laying horizontally overnight, but no luck so far.

Is it going to fix by itself after a few more pump-ups, or is the tire bad?

Comment: It might just need more sealant to reach the area to actually seal, which may take a few more rides/agitation on your part, assuming you seated the tire properly (e.g. with a compressor, so you get a huge volume of air in quickly).

Comment: Yeah, I'll give it a couple more tries. The tire sits well on the rim, even when it deflates.

Comment: Is it really leaking through the sidewalls  or are you referring to the bead, the area where the tire contacts the rim?

Comment: Yeah, is it leaking through the rubber of the tire side, or through the joint between tire and rim?  If the tires themselves are leaking they probably are not fit for use tubeless -- either wrong design or the rubber is breaking down with age and under-inflation.  If the joint is leaking you either need more sealant or you need to find rims which are better suited to tubeless use.

Comment: you could try a different sealant or some of the crazy sealant hack techniques, but quite honestly I hate Conti tires for mountain tubeless (yes it's a personal opinion). Myself and several people I know have had endless leaking out the sidewalls, like osmosis out the sides of the tire. Also, mine started showing threads and fraying after just a couple months.

Comment: I don't run tubeless so take this with a shovelfull of salt, but slowly spinning the wheels with the bike on it's side (then the other side) should help coat the sidewalls.  Maybe do this a few times when you've not long put sealant in.

Comment: Are you inflating with air or CO2 or something else?   CO2 leaks out of a tyre very quickly.

Comment: I'd say if they are losing pressure that quickly, its probably not through the sidewalls, its more likely that either the bead isn't seated or the valve nut isnt tight enough.
Typically pressure lost through leaky sidewalls is in the ~0.5psi/hr range.
That said, conti tyres (not sure about the very newest casing) are notoriously hard to set up.  I had a set of xkings that took 2 weeks of riding to become fully sealed.
I found scrubbing the insides before installation, and spending a day with the wheels on their sides (on top of a bucket is ideal) doing 'shake and turn' every hour helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found Contis in general to be a bit harder to seal and take up to a few weeks of riding before they settle down.  I've tried Mountain King II and XKings both the "Protection" versions I also have friends who have tried this.

Two things that might help

1. Before fitting wipe the inside of the tyre with Isopropyl Alcohol.  The theory is it removes the "release compound" which the sealant might have issues with.
2. Put lots of sealant in (like 150-200ml) and ride for a couple of weeks.  You can then remove the excess sealant if they've settled down (either using a syringe through the valve or by pulling one side off the rim).  Riding generally seems to be much better than wheels sitting in the shed for sealing.

I've fitted 3 new Mountain King 2s and an XKing and the last two I fitted seemed to be better using the techniques above.  Obviously I've not done an "A/B" test so this is just my experience.  My current fix is to buy Maxxis instead which seem to go up no problem.

Comment: If sealing indoors you can also give the wheel a spin (at a variety of angles) every few hours to spread out the sealant.  I also found higher pressure also helped.

Comment: This, I had an awful experience with a pair of X/Race Kings RS tires last year, they didn't seal in 3 months, I've used all the tricks, except for Revoseal instead of Stan's.

Comment: The answer as above is always more sealant and buy Maxxis EXOs. Some brands require more sealant than others and TR tyres in themselves are lighter and more porous than USTs. USTs can be inflated without sealant at all.

Comment: Contra @DWGKNZ I have had the same problem with Maxxis EXO/TR Ikons.

Comment: Obviously anecdotal but I had no issues with Maxxis Ardent EXO.  80ml of sealant and one ride and that was pretty much it for a couple of months (when I topped it up with sealant as I was doing all my tubeless wheels).

Comment: @Klaster_1 the RS version of conti tyres are not supposed to be air tight, they are very much a race only tyre that whilst you can inflate tubeless with sealant, will only stay that way for the duration of a race.  You need the 'protection' casing for proper tubeless compatibility

Comment: Continental MK Protection tire bubbles like ginger ale under water after three weeks of riding and bringing back to LBS for resealing

Answer (score 1):

I've used several sets of tubeless ready Maxxis Ikons with Stan's sealant and they've always leaked slowly through the sidewalls for several weeks before they settle down and hold air long term.

The ultra-light sidewalls needed the latex sealant to seep through and dry to maintain full air-tightness I theorize.